# Redirect after registration and login

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying build site to learn django. The site has registrations based on django's default system. Default django's model User related to my custom model Profile OneToOne relationship to add required fields like name, lastname, acronym, photo and bio. Users can fill and change these fields on thier pages. Also every user have URL which create default get_absolute_url method. How i can set after-registaration redirect to URL user's? I tried this:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
"""
This model represents profile each user 
including those registred by OAuth system.
"""
user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='Профиль пользователя', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=200)
last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=200)
patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length=200, blank=True)
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Аватар', default='avatar.png')
bio = models.TextField('Информация о себе', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Профиль пользователя: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('profile_detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Профиль' 
    verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'
    ordering = ['last_name']
```

view.py

```
    class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    paginate_by = 10


class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_detail.html'


class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'patronymic', 'profile_picture', 'bio']
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_form.html'
    success_url = ''
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProfileList.as_view(), name='profiles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', ProfileUpdate.as_view(), name='profile_form'),
    path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

views.py (main app where was written registr function)

```
def register(request, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            messages.success(request, 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались')
            return redirect('profile_detail')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка регистрации')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'news/register.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: You do not create a `Profile` in your `register` function?

Comment: first I created this site, and then I decided to add user pages, I think it would be better to transfer registration to the app with a profile, but I want to first understand how to request a redirect after authorization

Comment: a request to *where*? You redirect to `profile_detail`, but without a `Profile`, there is no item to show *details* from.

Comment: yes, you're right, i just wanted to show where i want redirect, it will something like return redirect ('profile_detail/USER_PK'), but I can't do it

Comment: `return redirect('profile_detail', pk=user.pk)`, but this is the *user* primary key, not that of the profile, so it will (likely) redirect to the "wrong" profile.

Comment: yes, this raised a 404 error since there is no user with id = 9, I created profiles with only id = 1 and id = 2, but thanks to you I was able to get to the data from the profile model table: return redirect ('profile_detail', pk = user.profile.pk). Now it works, write me an answer to this question, I will accept it from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`redirect(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) where you pass the name of the view and positional and named parameters, so:

```
return redirect('profile_detail', pk=profile.pk)
```

with *`profile`* the profile to which to redirect. If you thus constructed a `Profile` for the `user` you register, you can use:

```
return redirect('profile_detail', pk=user.profile.pk)
```